# How to convert image sequence to video using the VSE?

Tags: rendering, animation, video-sequence-editor, image

I've exported all my frames to .png.

Could you please explain (step by step) how to convert images to video using the video sequence editor? I used to export as .avi raw before, but because I'm having to constantly start again anytime I come across an error, I've decided to change my method.

Comment: This video helped me render 901 images exported from Google Earth Studio into a 60fps MP4: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LmxaYwmewWs

Answer (score 28):

In video sequence editor choose "Image".

[image]

Use <kbd>B</kbd> to select your frames quickly.

[image]

In properties> Render> Output, choose an output location.

Directly below, in properties> Render> Encoding, choose a video format (here I've chosen "H.264"). Select "RGB" right next to it, and hit "Animation" at the top.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, please the images are not display in video sequence window and how can I render audio with with?

Comment: You need to click "Image" in VSE> Add. (first picture)

Comment: Above "image", there is an option to choose "audio".

Comment: Am I supposed to do this in the same project or in a new, separate project? Because, I did this in the same project (2.81, add workspace -> Video Editing), and though it did create a video out of the PNG's, it seemed to have messed up with rendering. Clicking render did not seem to render the 3D scene but the PNG files. I deleted the "Strip" and closed the "Video Editing", but there still seemed to be weird errors like when trying to enable "denoise", it said it could not find the PNG file (I had deleted them all), etc.