# Is my animation supposed to render frame by frame?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation

i am just starting out of blender. i found a tutorial on how to make a text animation and it is rendering it frame by frame.. it is taking 10 minutes a frame and there are 140 frames. it is still rendering as i write this. i am using the cycles render engine..

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the world of rendering. I have had renders take WEEKS! There are so many variables that it is hard to say if it is good for your computer. CPU/GPU, Ram, How many samples you choose, objects in the scene,  there are so many things it could be. That does seem a little high but if you are on an older computer then it makes perfect sense.

Comment: Hi. What particularly is the question? That it is taking so long? Also, please make sure your question title is descriptive of the issue you are having. If you need to update your question you can use the [edit] link below it.

Comment: my question is @RayMairlot, is it supposed to render the animation frame by frame?

Comment: All animations are always rendered frame by frame. If you mean if it is supposed to render each frame to a separate file, then the answer is yes as well, that is the recommended way. Never render directly to a video file.

Comment: Animations are a series of frames, they get rendered one at the time.

Answer (score 1):

An animation is perhaps best rendered frame by frame to seperate image files and then consolidated to a video file.

Heres why:  If your video fails to complete you lose it all. You still have the blender scene. In a long animation if it fails at say frame 64, you cn simply start it again and you will have all the individual frames to combine.

You can also farm the job out to a render farm , but there are issues there as well.

When I did the Dissolve tutorial (if thats what you did ) I think it took just over 1 minute per frame. Mine was 960 x 540

my PC - an intel celeron J1900 1.9 quad processor. Blender does not recognise a GPU (video card)

Comment: well i have a VERY old computer. i left my dissolve animation to render overnight and it only got to 25 frames after nine hours! @Markr i still got like... 135 frames left :(

Comment: And this question explains how to do the image -> video: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52230/how-to-convert-image-sequence-to-video-using-the-vse