# Watch Frames of Animation Already Rendered While Still Rendering

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation

If halfway through rendering all frames of an animation with Cycles, is it possible to watch a video of the frames that have already been rendered?
Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Use *Video Sequence Editor* to create a movie from the sequence of images you've got: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52230/how-to-convert-image-sequence-to-video-using-the-vse

Comment: it depends on wether your rendering to a movie tile (eg. avi.) or seperate image frames

Comment: Thanks for the help. So it is only possible if you're rendering separate image frames, not an avi?

Comment: Rendering directly as a video file is not recommended. Render as an image sequence first and encode to video later.

Comment: @cegaton thank you for the advice, I'll be sure to do so in future. However for the case of rendering directly as a video file, is it possible to or not?

Comment: http://web.purplefrog.com/~thoth/blender/python-cookbook/render-to-pngs.html is my essay about rendering to images instead of a video.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the helpful comments.

For anyone that finds this in the future with the same question, if you just cancel the render with escape it will save the avi up to frame you were up to, so you can just note down what frame that was and start rendering again from after that and then combine the avi.