# How to export a sequence of images as a video file in Blender 2.8

Tags: animation, image, eevee-render-engine

I'm using blender 2.8 and on the video sequencer I added an image sequence of an animation I'm making. I now have a strip and I'm happy with the result. How do I then export it as a video file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert image sequence to video using the VSE?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52230/how-to-convert-image-sequence-to-video-using-the-vse)

Comment: I would not mark this as a possible duplicate because the question was relevant to Blender 2.8 and the old answer demonstrates the solution for an older version of Blender with different interface. This answer has the relevant Blender 2.8 images, however the solution is the same but the interface is different. If someone new searches for this for Blender 2.8 then by going to the older answer may confuse them since the interface images do not relate. This is from a new Blender user prospective, if someone used earlier version of Blender then it should not have a problem with the old answer.

Comment: You could have taken a screenshot and suggest an edit in the same time you wrote this extra long comment @Sprad001

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what screenshot you refer to because the person answered for this question already provided one. I only pointed out that this answer is was for the for 2.80 and the linked one is for older Blender@brockmann

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

Go to the **Output Tab** in the Properties Window. You can specify your output formats there, video included.

Comment: how is this related to the video sequencer...?