# Video rendering in images

Tags: rendering

When I render my videos in blender they render in images. Is there a way to render it to a video? I tried to search for a video on youtube but I didn't find something useful if someone could hep i would be thankful

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to render an animation as video in Blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15142/how-to-render-an-animation-as-video-in-blender)    https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/148130/how-can-i-get-rendered-animation-to-video-instead-of-a-bunch-of-pictures

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

in the output settings change the file format to ffmpeg (or any other movie format you find)

[image]

Comment: thanks that helped me

Comment: if it helped, please check the checkmark left to my answer. Thanks.