# Render out a video of an animation

Tags: rendering

I have been following a tutorial on YouTube that instructs how to create a wrecking ball that uses a rigid body to smash some cubes. In the video, the person who created the tutorial made an animated video of the wrecking ball. How do I do that? Please help with detailed instructions (in Blender 2.7)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For several reasons but mostly because of the colour range provided by some of the available image formats, you **always** want to render your animation to an *image sequence* (preferably `.exr` in case you are doing serious work) and compile the images into a video container like `.mov`, `.mp4` or `whatever` afterwards.

You can even compile the sequence using Blenders [Video Sequence Editor](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/52237/31447) or any other video package of your choice (depending on what you got access to) like `resolve`, `ffmpeg` or `handbrake` to only name a few out of hundreds of *free* options: [Comparison of video container formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_video_container_formats) on Wikipedia.