# Bad quality rendereing videos with Eevee

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, shadows

I'm trying to render a video with Eevee but I'm getting a really bad video quality.

When I render an image it looks perfect, everything looks smooth: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAyhR.jpg

But when I render a video, the background gets pixelated and with really bad quality: https://i.stack.imgur.com/juj50.jpg

These are the settings that I'm using: https://i.stack.imgur.com/88vXR.jpg

WHen I render it with Cycles it looks good but I need to render it with Eeevee so I would like to know if there are any way to fix this.

Thanks :)

Comment: Hi. Please use the built-in uploader when adding images. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post . Thanks.

Comment: Recommend, *always* render as image sequence (preferably exr), then use the VSE to compile the images into a video: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52230/how-to-convert-image-sequence-to-video-using-the-vse

Comment: How can I render as image sequence?

Comment: Pretty simple: in the "Output Properties" -> "Output"-dialog, choose "EXR" (or PNG) as file format.
Blender will automatically save the images with incrementing numbers, so you can later combine the frames into a video