# How to Export Render As Video

Tags: rendering, export

I made a small animation. Very simple, just a floating cube and a color changing light. After fighting a bit with key frames it was time to render, I realized I have no idea how to export this.

How do I export the video?

Comment: You can start by reading the doc : https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/output/index.html If you've gotr any specific question after that, feel free to ask it.

Comment: in my opinion the basic format is Properties panel > Output > Output, File Format > FFmpeg, Encoding > Container > Mpeg4, and in Properties panel > Render > Color Management > View Transform > Standard. Now it's also good to choose File Format > PNG, then import all the images into the video editor.

Comment: I'd recommend render to OpenEXR and compile the resulting image sequence using ffmpeg or the VSE: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52230/how-to-convert-image-sequence-to-video-using-the-vse

Comment: @brockmann is right - Render all single frames as EXR and then compile into video later. Only ever render directly to video if you have very short sequences. Why? If you render single frames and your computer crashes, you can restart the rendering from there and lose nothing. If you render directly to video and something bad happens before completion, you have to start from the beginning and may lose hours and hours of precious render time!