# Why my rendering slows down and stops at an arbitrary frame?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, workflow, encoding

When I’ve tried to render an animation, the first frame seems to take way longer than it usually does. Then, I return a few hours later, and it seems to have stopped at frame 26 or 31, when usually the render would’ve been finished under normal circumstances.

I’m using the EEVEE engine with all of the render settings how I usually have them, outputting to ffmpeg mp4, perceptually lossless, with the default sampling settings. The animation is 400 frames long and all the physics have been baked.
One thing to note, before rendering in EEVEE, I tried to render the animation in cycles before realizing it was taking too long, so I canceled the render and tried to render it again in EEVEE, changing all the appropriate output settings accordingly. In the past I’ve rendered a few animations in EEVEE without ever having this issue.

Comment: Perhaps your renders are getting more CPU/GPU/RAM demanding.   This may be difficult to predict.   Long ago I noticed with more RAM I got less crashes.  I sometime shut down all other applications.  I cannot not, no I cannot ask what are your machine specifications.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend *always* render to image files (preferably [OpenEXR](https://www.openexr.com/)). Once the rendering is done, you can easily [encode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_codec) the resulting sequence into a *movie clip* like `.mp4` or `.mov` using [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/), [Davinci Resolve](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/davinciresolve) or even [Blender's VSE](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52230/how-to-convert-image-sequence-to-video-using-the-vse).

Comment: Blender has SE Sequence Editor for making movies.  What would be the advantage of using ffmpeg?

Comment: It's for getting easily movie file. If the output stops in the middle, I first need to get all frames data.

Comment: Because it's way faster, up to date (latest codecs) and not that error-prone like the VSE is @atomicbezierslinger