# How to fix my blender not rendering?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, error

Hi I am a beginner in blender, it worked fine until I tried to render a video from video editing section in blender and after that my render stopped working, here's before:

[image: screenshot before rendering a video]

And here's after:

[image: screenshot after rendering the video]

Comment: Recommended way is encode *after* the actual rendering is done. Render to an *image sequence* perferably *OpenEXR* and use *ffmpeg* or *Davinci Resolve* to compile your image sequence into a movie clip. If you would like to stay in Blender, see: [How to convert image sequence to video using the VSE?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52230/how-to-convert-image-sequence-to-video-using-the-vse) BTW: Please take the [tour] to learn about how this site works.

Comment: It seems to me that you're stuck on the render result window and all you have to do is to close this window by pressing **ESC** or the **X** button in top-right of the window?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up