# i have rendered my animation but how do i turn it to a video

Tags: file-browser

i have rendered my animation but i realized it was saved in different pictures.i tried changing it to a Xxiv file but that didn't work(movie file on blender 2.78). how can i change it to a video[[image: where my folder is][1]]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52230/how-to-convert-image-sequence-to-video-using-the-vse/52237#52237

Answer (score 0):

Open 2 *Video Sequencer (VSE)* windows, one as *Preview*, the other as *Sequencer*, in the *Sequencer* press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> *(Add) > Image/Sequence*:

[image]

Then this time export as *FFmpeg* format.